# Is possible use UIControl with elements like a custom UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uistackview, uicontrol

My question could be simple to answer.
Is it possible to use an UIControl that contains elements like UIStackView or labels?
When I add a UIControl, I can use it like UIButton, but then I added a StackView with two UILabels the interaction was lost, because the StackView is on the UIControl but block the interaction.

Is there a way to do this? A custom UIButton using an UIControl and labels into storyboards?

Thanks!

Comment: can You please elaborate what does it mean "When I add a UIControl, I can use it like UIButton"? Do You create a child of UIControl or just add some subview to it? have you tried to set isUserInteractionEnabled = false to stack and labels?

Comment: This is a very broad question I highly recommend you go to google (or your favorite search engine) and search for: `swift custom uicontrol` ... you'll find lots of articles / tutorials / examples / etc.